# Finding residues of a simple case

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given $n\in \mathbb {Z}\gt 0$, $m = n^2 + 5n, k = m^2 +n$, need find residues for $k,m \mod 6$ and find a relation between them, if it exists.

The residues for $n \pmod 6$ are $\{0,1,...5\}$, for $5n \pmod 6$ are $(0,5,4,3,2,1)$, for $n^2 \pmod 6$ are $(0,1,4,3,4,1)$. For, $m = n^2 + 5n \pmod 6$ are $(0,0,2,0,0,2)$. For, $m^2 \pmod 6$ are $(0,0,4,0,0,4)$; and for $k = m^2 +n \pmod 6$ are $(0,1,0,3,4,3)$.

The relationship between $m$ and $n$ is: $m = ?n$

The relationship between $k$ and $n$ is: $k = ?n$

Comment: What's the question?  For $n=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ we have $m=\{0,0,2,0,0,2\}$ and $k=\{0,1,0,3,4,3\}$, all $\pmod 6$.  Not sure what sort of relation you are hoping for.  clearly, $m\pmod 6$ does not determine $k\pmod 6$.

Comment: A relation can be formed based on say position of element $n \pmod 6$, say the third (residue=$2$), and fifth (residue = $5$), form a particular value ($2$), rest all $0$. Much tougher for guessing for $k$. Also, it is a book's exercise question.

Comment: Not following.  What are you trying to guess?  Everything is determined.  It is true that knowing both $m$ and $k$ determines $n$...perhaps that is what you were looking for?

Comment: The book asked about :"writing $k$ in terms of $n$ and express the assertion as a theorem about $n$". I changed the wording and included $m$ also. I hoped that the book would not simply ask: $k = (n^2+5n)^2 + n$. I hoped that the book would ask for what values of $n \pmod 6$, there would be a given value of $k$.

Comment: Why would you change the wording?  What you wrote makes no sense.  Please pose the question as it was originally worded.

Comment: Perhaps the question intended you to simplify the expression $k=(n^2+5n)^2+n$.  It should simplify considerably.  For instance, $\pmod 6$ we have $n^3=n,n^4=n^2$.

Comment: I hope you have found $n^3 \pmod 6$ and found the residues same as that for $n \pmod 6$, and similarly for $n^4$ and $n^2$. But, I cannot find the reason for finding relation between different powers of $n^i \pmod 6, i \in \mathbb{N}$, at least from the question given.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow what  you are saying.  Good luck.

Comment: Your earlier comment stated: $k = n^4 + 25n^2 + 10n^3 + n$. How then the next line came to the issue of $n^3 = n $ or $n^4 = n^2$ in modulo $6$ case is not clear.

Comment: What's not clear?  You have a quartic which you can reduce to a quadratic (at least). That is a huge simplification!  But, honestly, I have no idea what the underlying question is here.  What you wrote doesn't make sense.  You don't even mention that the modulus is $6$.

Comment: I have corrected that mistake of not specifying modulus in the question line. So, as for $\mod 6$, there is a equivalence between $n^4$ and $n^2$, and between $n^3$ and $n$, so can reduce the equation to a quadratic: $k = 26n^2 + 11n $. Thanks a lot for the help.If I missed some next step(s), please give hint for that.

Comment: That expression simplifies further.  we get $k\equiv 2n^2-n\pmod 6$.

Comment: Although difficult to understand the significance, as till now used this sort of modulo arithmetic (equivalent in terms of residue finding) only on integers, but hope will come to terms with it soon.

Comment: I request you to shed some light on the equivalence under modulo operation, to be used for a non-integer like $n$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.  As a potentially interesting exercise in this example, try to write $n$ as a function of $k,m$.  We can see from the list of residues that there is such a function.  Hint:  from the simplification, we know that $k=2n^2-n$.  But $m=n^2+5n$.  If you consider $k-2m$ at least you cancel the quadratic term...

Comment: As a general note:  often, not always but often, confusion in mathematics comes from a lack of clarity and precision.  I think that's what is going on here.  Try to ask a precise question...something that might be expected to have a clear, unambiguous answer.  Sure, it is sometimes useful and interesting to speculate loosely but in the end things need to be stated clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try my best to adhere to it. Regarding the expression of $n$ as a function of $k,m$, answer has been given by you already, i.e. $n = \dfrac {(k - 2m)}{-11}$. Regarding my last question, I meant that by residue modulo, I have dealt till now only with integers, say $91 \equiv 1 \pmod 6$, but here $n \pmod 6$ is a set of values of residues, and hence applying the residue operation is not clear theoretically to me, as you have stated: $k \equiv 2n^2 - n \pmod 6$.

Comment: Don't write things like fractions in modular arithmetic.  $n=k-2m$, pure and simple.  after all $-11=1$ so why have that term at all?  Get in the habit of simplifying algebraic formulae.  It is always a good idea, period.

Comment: I feel that my earlier question, also repeated with an example in my last response, is still waiting for your kind response.